# fw_printenv Not showing env variables from uboot.env

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, u-boot

I am working on an OrangePi Zero, attempting to get fw_printenv to work properly. So far, I am at a loss. Thank you in advance for any help you all might be able to provide.

I am running the following u-boot script prior to booting the kernel:

```
fdt addr ${fdt_addr} && fdt get value bootargs /chosen bootargs

test -n "${BOOT_ORDER}" || setenv BOOT_ORDER "A B"
test -n "${BOOT_A_LEFT}" || setenv BOOT_A_LEFT 3
test -n "${BOOT_B_LEFT}" || setenv BOOT_B_LEFT 3
test -n "${BOOT_DEV}" || setenv BOOT_DEV "mmc 0:1"

setenv bootpart
setenv raucslot

for BOOT_SLOT in "${BOOT_ORDER}"; do
  if test "x${bootpart}" != "x"; then
    # skip remaining slots
  elif test "x${BOOT_SLOT}" = "xA"; then
    if test ${BOOT_A_LEFT} -gt 0; then
      setexpr BOOT_A_LEFT ${BOOT_A_LEFT} - 1
      echo "Found valid RAUC slot A"
      setenv bootpart "/dev/mmcblk0p2"
      setenv raucslot "A"
      setenv BOOT_DEV "mmc 0:2"
    fi
  elif test "x${BOOT_SLOT}" = "xB"; then
    if test ${BOOT_B_LEFT} -gt 0; then
      setexpr BOOT_B_LEFT ${BOOT_B_LEFT} - 1
      echo "Found valid RAUC slot B"
      setenv bootpart "/dev/mmcblk0p3"
      setenv raucslot "B"
      setenv BOOT_DEV "mmc 0:3"
    fi
  fi
done

setenv bootcmd_pxe ""

if test -n "${bootpart}"; then
  setenv bootargs console=${console} console=tty1 root=/dev/${rootdev} rootwait panic=10 ${extra}
  setenv bootargs "${bootargs} root=${bootpart} rauc.slot=${raucslot}"
  saveenv
else
  echo "No valid RAUC slot found. Resetting tries to 3"
  setenv BOOT_A_LEFT 3
  setenv BOOT_B_LEFT 3
  saveenv
  reset
fi

fatload mmc 0:1 ${kernel_addr_r} @@KERNEL_IMAGETYPE@@
if test ! -e mmc 0:1 uboot.env; then saveenv; fi;

load mmc 0:1 ${fdt_addr_r} ${fdtfile} || load mmc 0:1 ${fdt_addr_r} boot/${fdtfile}
load mmc 0:1 ${kernel_addr_r} zImage || load mmc 0:1 ${kernel_addr_r} boot/zImage || load mmc 0:1 ${kernel_addr_r} uImage || load mmc 0:1 ${kernel_addr_r} boot/uImage
bootz ${kernel_addr_r} - ${fdt_addr_r} || bootm ${kernel_addr_r} - ${fdt_addr_r}
```

This script appears to run without issue and the env vars it sets are saved to `/boot/uboot.env`. The /boot partition is mmcblk0p1 on my device. My uboot.env file looks as follows:

```
root@orange-pi-zero:~# cat /boot/uboot.env 
�5�`BOOT_A_LEFT=3OOT_B_LEFT=3BOOT_DEV=mmc 0:2BOOT_ORDER=A Barch=armbaudrate=115200board=sunxiboard_name=sunxiboot_a_script=load ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} ${scriptaddr} ${prefix}${script}; source ${scriptaddr}boot_efi_binary=if fdt addr ${fdt_addr_r}; then bootefi bootmgr ${fdt_addr_r};else bootefi bootmgr ${fdtcontroladdr};fi;load ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} ${kernel_addr_r} efi/boot/bootarm.efi; if fdt addr ${fdt_addr_r}; then bootefi ${kernel_addr_r} ${fdt_addr_r};else bootefi ${kernel_addr_r} ${fdtcontroladdr};fiboot_extlinux=sysboot ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} any ${scriptaddr} ${prefix}${boot_syslinux_conf}boot_net_usb_start=usb startboot_prefixes=/ /boot/boot_script_dhcp=boot.scr.uimgboot_scripts=boot.scr.uimg boot.scrboot_syslinux_conf=extlinux/extlinux.confboot_targets=fel mmc0 usb0 pxe dhcp bootargs=console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/ rootwait panic=10 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rauc.slot=Abootcmd=run distro_bootcmdbootcmd_dhcp=run boot_net_usb_start; if dhcp ${scriptaddr} ${boot_script_dhcp}; then source ${scriptaddr}; fi;setenv efi_fdtfile ${fdtfile}; if test -z "${fdtfile}" -a -n "${soc}"; then setenv efi_fdtfile ${soc}-${board}${boardver}.dtb; fi; setenv efi_old_vci ${bootp_vci};setenv efi_old_arch ${bootp_arch};setenv bootp_vci PXEClient:Arch:00010:UNDI:003000;setenv bootp_arch 0xa;if dhcp ${kernel_addr_r}; then tftpboot ${fdt_addr_r} dtb/${efi_fdtfile};if fdt addr ${fdt_addr_r}; then bootefi ${kernel_addr_r} ${fdt_addr_r}; else bootefi ${kernel_addr_r} ${fdtcontroladdr};fi;fi;setenv bootp_vci ${efi_old_vci};setenv bootp_arch ${efi_old_arch};setenv efi_fdtfile;setenv efi_old_arch;setenv efi_old_vci;bootcmd_fel=if test -n ${fel_booted} && test -n ${fel_scriptaddr}; then echo '(FEL boot)'; source ${fel_scriptaddr}; fibootcmd_mmc0=devnum=0; run mmc_bootbootcmd_pxe=bootcmd_usb0=devnum=0; run usb_bootbootdelay=2bootfstype=fatbootm_size=0xa000000bootpart=/dev/mmcblk0p2console=ttyS0,115200cpu=armv7devplist=1dfu_alt_info_ram=kernel ram 0x42000000 0x1000000;fdt ram 0x43000000 0x100000;ramdisk ram 0x43300000 0x4000000distro_bootcmd=for target in ${boot_targets}; do run bootcmd_${target}; doneefi_dtb_prefixes=/ /dtb/ /dtb/current/eth1addr=12:42:0f:ba:44:2eethaddr=02:42:0f:ba:44:2efdt_addr_r=0x43000000fdtcontroladdr=5bf59080fdtfile=sun8i-h2-plus-orangepi-zero.dtbfileaddr=43100000filesize=77ckernel_addr_r=0x42000000load_efi_dtb=load ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} ${fdt_addr_r} ${prefix}${efi_fdtfile}mmc_boot=if mmc dev ${devnum}; then devtype=mmc; run scan_dev_for_boot_part; fimmc_bootdev=0partitions=name=loader1,start=8k,size=32k,uuid=${uuid_gpt_loader1};name=loader2,size=984k,uuid=${uuid_gpt_loader2};name=esp,size=128M,bootable,uuid=${uuid_gpt_esp};name=system,size=-,uuid=${uuid_gpt_system};preboot=usb startpxefile_addr_r=0x43200000ramdisk_addr_r=0x43300000raucslot=Ascan_dev_for_boot=echo Scanning ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart}...; for prefix in ${boot_prefixes}; do run scan_dev_for_extlinux; run scan_dev_for_scripts; done;run scan_dev_for_efi;scan_dev_for_boot_part=part list ${devtype} ${devnum} -bootable devplist; env exists devplist || setenv devplist 1; for distro_bootpart in ${devplist}; do if fstype ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} bootfstype; then run scan_dev_for_boot; fi; done; setenv devplistscan_dev_for_efi=setenv efi_fdtfile ${fdtfile}; if test -z "${fdtfile}" -a -n "${soc}"; then setenv efi_fdtfile ${soc}-${board}${boardver}.dtb; fi; for prefix in ${efi_dtb_prefixes}; do if test -e ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} ${prefix}${efi_fdtfile}; then run load_efi_dtb; fi;done;if test -e ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} efi/boot/bootarm.efi; then echo Found EFI removable media binary efi/boot/bootarm.efi; run boot_efi_binary; echo EFI LOAD FAILED: continuing...; fi; setenv efi_fdtfilescan_dev_for_extlinux=if test -e ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} ${prefix}${boot_syslinux_conf}; then echo Found ${prefix}${boot_syslinux_conf}; run boot_extlinux; echo SCRIPT FAILED: continuing...;��scan_dev_for_scripts=for script in ${boot_scripts}; do if test -e ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} ${prefix}${script}; then echo Found U-Boot script ${prefix}${script}; run boot_a_script; echo SCRIPT FAILED: continuing...; fi; donescriptaddr=0x43100000serial#=02c000420fba442esoc=sunxistderr=serialstdin=serial,usbkbdstdout=serialusb_boot=usb start; if usb dev ${devnum}; then devtype=usb; run scan_dev_for_boot_part; fiuuid_gpt_esp=c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93buuid_gpt_system=69dad710-2ce4-4e3c-b16c-21a1d49abed3
```

With this in mind, the following is returned when I run `fw_printenv`:

```
root@orange-pi-zero:~# fw_printenv
BOOT_A_LEFT=3
```

Oddly, it seems like only the first variable is output. Below is the relevant portion of the strace:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/fw_env.config", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=30, ...}) = 0
read(3, "/boot/uboot.env 0x0000 0x4000\n", 4096) = 30
lstat64("/boot", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=16384, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/boot/uboot.env", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=131072, ...}) = 0
stat64("/boot/uboot.env", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=131072, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/boot/uboot.env", O_RDONLY) = 4
close(4)                                = 0
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/lock/fw_printenv.lock", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
flock(3, LOCK_EX)                       = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/boot/uboot.env", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "\3365\337`BOOT_A_LEFT=3\0\0OOT_B_LEFT=3\0"..., 16384) = 16384
close(4)                                = 0
fstat64(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(0x4, 0x40), ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, TCGETS, {B115200 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
write(1, "BOOT_A_LEFT=3\n", 14BOOT_A_LEFT=3
)         = 14
flock(3, LOCK_UN)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

So, it seems to be finding my uboot.env file with no issue, based on that stack trace (and since it seems to read the first variable in it). As for why it cannot seem to read the others, I'm at a bit of a loss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I identified the crux of the issue. It seems to have ultimately been caused by using an incorrect config in my fw_env.config file. In what I posted previously, it looked like as follows:

`/boot/uboot.env 0x0000 0x4000`

However, the second value (0x4000) refers to the size of the environment. In my case, on the OrangePi Zero, my environment is 0x20000.

Once my fw_env.config looked like as follows, things worked.

`/boot/uboot.env 0x0000 0x20000`

Answer (score 4):

The uboot.env file seems to contain a double NUL termination after the `BOOT_A_LEFT=3` value:

```
read(4, "\3365\337`BOOT_A_LEFT=3\0\0OOT_B_LEFT=3\0"..., 16384) = 16384
```

I suspect the file may have been overwritten one or more times, and that you are seeing a combination of old contents (the oddly named `OOT_B_LEFT` value and everything that follows it), and new contents (a single `BOOT_A_LEFT` value).

The reason for the difference in the output from `cat` and `fw_printenv` is that `cat` will print the contents of the entire file whereas `fw_printenv` will stop printing variables after encountering a double NUL termination, which indicates the end of the environment block.

Comment: What you point out is very much correct and is not something I noticed! Thanks! It seems to have resolved itself once I increased the environment length in the fw_env.config to the appropriate value